# How to associate a grouped product to a configurable product in Magento?

Tags: magento

Ok, SO. I have a configurable product setup with the simple products already associated. No problem. I want to associate one more product...a grouped product containing all the simple products that this configurable product is made up of. This is to allow wholesale customers to buy a set (1 of each of these simple products) at once rather than have to order each individually. Hope you're following!..

From the same attribute set that I created the configurable product, I've created the grouped product. By doing this, I expected it to show up as a viable product to associate, since all the attributes match up. It's not.

Any idea as to why Magento won't let me associate a grouped product to a configurable product, and how I go about doing that? Thanks! I appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see. I chose not to use the bundled products because the set is pre-determined. The wholesale customer will not have the ability to customize or choose which simple products go into that set. What I've done, is added "Set" to the appropriate configurable attribute and created a simple product to represent the full set (which does have its very own SKU).

Now we plan to install this module, and restrict the simple product Sets to only wholesale customer groups. http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/catalog-permissions.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't associate a grouped product to a configurable product.

Is there any reason why you have chosen not to use bundled products?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to custom build this, Magento natively doesn't allow you to associate configurable and grouped products. Bundle might be a better way to do this. I'd think that you could adapt the business logic behind it to fit better with bundle products.

Now that being said... you can easily create new product types in Magento that could fit your needs better, the only question is how much time and money can you invest on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can this with this :

Go to simple product then select manage product and then custom option set

```
is required: no
```

Then you can add this configurable product in grouped product.